# Check if a anchor exists in the url Prototype JavaScript

Tags: javascript, anchor

A bit of a basic question but how may I check if a anchor is in the url when I load the page?

For example www.mysite.com/mypage#show

And then in the JavaScript I can go if #show exists do this

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

plain js:

```
if( window.location.hash == '#show' )
```